# Passing multi-dimentional array from function to function

Tags: c, function, pointers, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference

Concept:I'm trying to pass an array to a function1, and then pass it again to another function2 that is called by function1.All i'm going to do is print the array.(the array i'm passing):

> 6 5  //the number of lines and number of columns
>
> 7 4 5 2 7
>
> 6 9 1 6 3
>
> 9 2 7 9 8
>
> 8 8 1 7 2
>
> 2 3 1 8 4
>
> 4 6 5 4 6

So my main will look something like this:

```
int main()
{
    int n,m; //number of lines,number of columns
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);

    int **array;
    array = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        array[i] = malloc(m * sizeof(int));
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&array[i][j]);
        }
    }

    function1(n,m,array);

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
}
```

function1 looks like this:

```
void function1(int n,int m,int **array)
{
    function2(n,m,&array);
}
```

and then function2:

```
void function2(int n,int m,int ***array)
{
        printf("%d %d\n",n,m);
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
            {
                printf("%d ",*array[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
 }
```

What am'i doing so wrong that not only do i get a segmentation fault but also it prints outs this:
6 5
7 6 9 8 2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
It prints the first column as a line.

Comment: Brackets have higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). Use `printf("%d ",(*array)[i][j]);`

Comment: Why are you adding an extra level of indirection in `function2`?

Comment: @Barmar i don't know why..it was the only way i could even print something pointer-wise.Any other case i got errors while compiling

Comment: Why do you need to print pointer-wise? Declare the argument `int **array` in `function2()`, pass `array` instead of `&array`, and print `array[i][j]`.

Comment: @Barmar I have to declare my array in main the way i need it for a project.

Comment: That should be explained in the question. And the solution is to just fix the syntax as pointed out by @JohnnyMopp

Comment: @Barmar I said what the concept was~You just tried to change the concept.And yes JonnyMopp 's comment was very useful

Comment: Where did you say that concept in the question? It just says "pass it again to another function2". It doesn't say that function2 needs to access the elements using pointers.

Comment: @Barmar So you're saying that it could be passed without pointers from main to function1 to function2?

Comment: It's already a pointer, you just pass the same pointer from one function to another. You don't need to pass a pointer to the pointer.

Comment: @Barmar i understand what you mean but when i passed it with ** i got a Segmentation....

Comment: You need to change how `function2()` is written if you make that change. The parameter should be declared `int **` instead of `int ***`, and you access it with `array[i][j]` instead of `(*array)[i][j]`.

Comment: @Barmar but i tried it and i got a segmentation if when i wrote something as simple as array[i][j] without any computations..

Comment: Hard to tell what you did wrong without seeing the full code, maybe you could post a new question about it.

Comment: @Barmar this is all the code there is really

Comment: What is? You haven't posted the revised versions of `function1` and `function2`.

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean?

Comment: We're talking about a version of the program where you pass `array` from `function1` to `function2` without adding another level of indirection. You change it to `void function2(int n,int m,int **array)`, call it as `function2(n,m,array);`, and use `array[i][j]` in `function2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @Johnny Mopp because brackets have higher precedence than * all i had to do was write (*array)[i][j] in opposition to *array[i][j].Thank you very much for the comment:)